# AngularUI MessageBox promise not invoked in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-10, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm running into the following problem, here's the code right away:

```js
// into some function invoked from ng-click

var msgbox = $dialog.messageBox(
    'Some Title',
    "Some message body", [{
        label: 'Button 1',
        result: 'RESULT 1',
    }, {
        label: 'Button 2',
        result: 'RESULT 2',
    }, {
        label: 'Button 3',
        result: 'RESULT 3',
    }]);

console.log('opening...');

msgbox.open().then(function (result) {
    console.log('result...');

    switch (result) {
        case 'RESULT 1':
            // do something here
            break;

        case 'RESULT 2':
            // do something else here
            break;

        case 'RESULT 3':
        default:
            // do nothing here
            break;
    }
});
```

In Chrome (v28.0.1500.95) and Firefox (v22), the *then* anonymous function is invoked and both logs are displayed in console. Application works as expected.

In IE10 (v10.0.9200) the *then* function is never invoked. Only the first log is displayed.
After closing the dialog by clicking whatever button, the UI becomes unresponsive: clicking on buttons or other UI controls has no effect (the vertical scrollbar works though).

If I had previously enabled debugging in IE Dev tools, the separate IE Dev window becomes really slow-responding as well. I thought something might have gone into an infinite loop, and I paused execution: after a long time, the Dev window usually showed a line in jQuery Event addEvent method.

Main libraries I'm using: JSON3 3.2.4, jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery UI 1.10.1, AngularJS 1.0.5, AngularUI 0.4.0, Angular UI Bootstrap 0.2.0.

Did anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what solved the issue, at least for me:

I upgraded *Angular UI Bootstrap* to **0.5.0**.
Before that, I also:

- checked for a newer version of *Angular UI*, with no luck
- upgraded *Angular* to 1.0.7, without any visible improvement on the issue.

On a side note, as of today I was not able to find v0.5.0 hosted on any CDN (only up to 0.4.0).

Comment: oh well, no other feedback and it works ... I'm going to set my own as the answer [(picture)](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/531527_325984170829377_802811007_n.jpg)